Deriving the telegrapher PDE from a run-and-tumble model
Generalized question
Under what conditions on $f(t,\vec{x},\vec{v})$ do we have
$$\mathbb{E}_{v}(\vec{v}^T \nabla_x^2 f(t,x,\vec{v}) \vec{v})=\mathbb{E}_v(\Delta_x f(t,x,v)),$$
where $v\sim \mathcal{U}(S^{n-1})$? Here $\nabla_x^2$ is the Hessian with respect to $x$, and $\Delta_x$ is the Laplacian.
Context:
A rather general run-and-tumble process can be defined as a process that travels at a finite constant velocity in between poisson arrival times, at which point it changes direction, picking a random direction, i.e., picking a vector uniformly distributed on the hypersphere. The infinitesimal generator of such process is
$$\mathscr{G} f = c \vec{v}^T \nabla_x f(x,v) +\lambda \int_{S^{n-1}} [f(x,v') -f(x,v)] \nu\{dv'\}.$$
Here, $\nu$ is the uniform measure on the hypersphere's surface. The transition density $f(t,x,v)$ then satisfies the Kolmogorov forward pde,
$$f_t + c v^T \nabla_x f = \lambda \int_{S^{n-1}} [f(t,x,v') -f(t,x,v)] \nu\{dv'\}.$$
We want to prove the following:
Conjecture:
Let
$$p(t,x) = \int_{S^{n-1}} f(t,x,v) \nu\{dv\}.$$
then $p$ solves the telegrapher PDE,
$$p_t = \frac12 \Box p,$$
where $\Box:-\frac{1}{c^2} \partial_tt+\Delta$ is the d'Alembertian operator with sign convention $(-1, 1,\dotsc, 1)$.
Proof Attempt Integrating the Kolmogorov forward PDE for $f$ over $v\in S^{n-1}$ with respect to the uniform measure on $S^{n-1}$ gives
$$p_t + \nabla_x \cdot \vec{J} = 0,$$
where
$$\vec{J} = \int_{S^{n-1}} cf \vec{v} \nu\{dv\}.$$
we have used the fact that $\vec{v}^T \nabla_x f = \nabla_x \cdot (f \vec{v})$. differentiating this with respect to $t$ gives
$$p_{tt} + \nabla_x \cdot \vec{J}_t = 0.$$
but
$$\vec{J}_t = \int_{S^{n-1}} c f_t \vec{v} \nu\{dv\}.$$
Now, multiply the original balanced kolmogorov forward pde for $f$ by $c\vec{v}$ and integrate over $S^{n-1}$. We obtain
$$\vec{J}_t + c^2\int (v^T \nabla_x f) v \nu\{dv\} = \lambda p \mathbb{E}(V)-\lambda \vec{J},$$
$$=-\lambda \vec{J}$$
since $\mathbb{E}(V)=0$. On the LHS we can pull out the gradient into a divergence, so that we obtain
$$\vec{J}_t + c^2 \int \nabla_x \cdot( f \vec{v}) \vec{v} \nu\{dv\}=-\lambda \vec{J}.$$
Applying the divergence $\nabla_x \cdot $ gives,
$$\nabla_x \cdot \vec{J}_t + c^2 \int_{S^{n-1}} \text{Tr}(vv^T \nabla_x^2 f) \nu\{dv\}=-\lambda \nabla_x \cdot \vec{J}.$$
Here we used the fact that $\nabla \cdot (\nabla \cdot (f \vec{v}) \vec{v}) = \text{Tr}(vv^T \nabla^2 f)$. Thus, substituting the expressions for $\nabla_x \cdot \vec{J}$ and $\nabla_x \cdot \vec{J}_t$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
    p_t &= -\nabla_x \cdot \vec{J} \\
        &= \frac{1}{\lambda } \left[\nabla_x \cdot \vec{J}_t + c^2 \int_{S^{n-1}} \text{Tr}(vv^T \nabla_x^2 f) \nu\{dv\}\right] \\
        &= \frac{1}{\lambda} \left[-p_{tt} + c^2 \int_{S^{n-1}} \text{Tr}(vv^T \nabla_x^2 f) \nu\{dv\}\right]
\end{align*}
from which the result follows if we can show that
$$\int_{S^{n-1}} \text{Tr}(vv^T \nabla_x^2 f) \nu\{dv\} = \Delta p,$$
and upon setting $\lambda = 2c^2$.
It is possible to show, by taking the Hessian of the original forward pde in $(t, x,v)$, multiplying by $v^T$ and $v$ on the left and right and using the trace trick to compute $\mathbb{E}[v^T \nabla_x^2 p v] = \text{Tr}(\nabla_x^2 p \mathbb{E}(vv^T))=\Delta_x p$, that
$$\mathbb{E}(v^T \nabla_x^2 f v) = -\frac{1}{\lambda}\mathbb{E}(v^T \nabla_x^2 f_t v + cv^T D_x[\nabla_x^2 f v]v) + \Delta_x p.$$
Thus, it suffices to show that that first expectation on the RHS is zero, i.e.
$$\mathbb{E}[v^T \nabla_x^2 f_t v ]=-c\mathbb{E}[v^T D_x[\nabla_x^2 f v] v].$$
Here $D_x[\cdot]$ is the Jacobian matrix wrt $x$.

I have tried to think of many ideas to tackle this. It doesn't seem to hold in general for arbitrary joint densities $f(X,V)$, by checking examples numerically, so it should depend on the fact that $f$ solves the integro-PDE of the run-and-tumble model. I know since $v$ is uniform on the hypersphere, it is rotationally invariant hence if $\nabla_x^2 f= Q \Lambda Q^T$, $Q^TQ = I$, i.e. orthogonal columns, then we have $\mathbb{E}(v^T \nabla_x^2 f v) = \mathbb{E}(v^T \Lambda v)$ where $\Lambda$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues of the Hessian of $f$. But I don't think this helps anywhere...
Is there something obvious I missed, or is it possible that this is not true?
Update 5/28/2024:
It is now obvious to me that if $v\sim \mathcal{U}(\{e_1,\dotsc, e_n\})$ then for each $t,x$, we indeed have
$$\mathbb{E}(v^T \nabla_x^2 f(t,x,v) v) = \mathbb{E}(\Delta_x f(t,x,v)).$$
Here the $e_i$ are the standard basis vectors, e.g. in $3$ dimensions $(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$. In fact this still holds if $v\sim \mathcal{U}(S)$ where $S$ is the finite set containing each $e_i$ up to a sign. This is not hard to see, so I will omit the computation. This case includes the classic one dimensional telegrapher process that switches velocities from $\pm c$, studied by Kac and Goldstein.
But the general case still eludes me and is now starting to appear likely to be false.
